# Error in logistic regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong. I am trying to perform a logistic regression in R. To test out the code, I have subset a small data frame of one row and all the columns. I ran the following code:

```
Cs <- c(A[,4],A[,5],A[,6],A[,7],A[,8],A[,9],A[,10],A[,11],A[,12],A[,13],A[,14],A[,15],A[,16],A[,17],A[,18])
Ts <- c(A[,19],A[,20],A[,21],A[,22],A[,23],A[,24],A[,25],A[,26],A[,27],A[,28],A[,29],A[,30],A[,31],A[,32],A[,33])
regions.X <- cbind(Cs, Ts)
regions.IV <- c('s','s','s','s','s','s','s','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c')
result <- glm(regions.X ~ regions.IV, family = 'binomial')
summary(result)$coefficients[2,4]
```

This code runs well. However when I use this code as a function in apply on the very same dataset:

```
region.log <- apply(A, MARGIN = 1, function(m){Cs <- c(m[4],m[5],m[6],m[7],m[8],m[9],m[10],m[11],m[12],m[13],m[14],m[15],m[16],m[17],m[18])
Ts <- c(m[19],m[20],m[21],m[22],m[23],m[24],m[25],m[26],m[27],m[28],m[29],m[30],m[31], m[32],m[33])
regions.X <- cbind(Cs, Ts)
regions.IV <- c('s','s','s','s','s','s','s','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c')
result <- glm(regions.X ~ regions.IV, family = 'binomial')
summary(result)$coefficients[2,4]})
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(13L, 15L, 11L, 10L, 17L,  : 
replacement has 30 rows, data has 15
```

I am not sure why the code would not work when it is used in apply. I am sure I must be missing something but I have not been able to figure that out.

Could I please some advice on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: did you examine the structure of your variables before running the model? or just expect that it would work?

Comment: I am unaware wow the structure would affect the same code from being used as a function in apply?

Comment: In any case, the structure of my test data frame is as follow: > str(A)
'data.frame': 1 obs. of  33 variables:
 $ chr    : Factor w/ 21 levels "chr1","chr10",..: 1
 $ start  : int 100027723
 $ end    : int 100028202
 $ numCs1 : num 32
 $ numCs2 : num 38
 $ numCs3 : num 30
 $ numCs4 : num 29
 $ numCs5 : num 43
 $ numCs6 : num 41
 $ numCs7 : num 34
 $ numCs8 : num 27
 $ numCs9 : num 29
 $ numCs10: num 29
 $ numCs11: num 31
 $ numCs12: num 30
 $ numCs13: num 53
 $ numCs14: num 52
 $ numCs15: num 54
 $ numTs1 : num 10
 $ numTs2 : num 16
 $ numTs3 : num 17
 $ numTs4 : num 9 .... etc

Comment: because you're doing this `apply(mtcars, 1, function(x) x[1:5])` vs this `mtcars[, 1:5]` in the first chunk of code. so please revisit my first comment without just blowing it off this time

Comment: I appreciate your input on this and am not trivializing your comments. Could you please clarify what you think the problem could be with the code? Please correct me if I have mistaken, as far as I understand when apply is used with MARGIN = 1 (e.g. apply(mtcars,1,function(x) x[1:5])), the MARGIN 1 tells the function I am iterating my rows so all I need is to specify the column index. In contrast, if I am not using the apply function, I need to specify both row and column indices thus mtcars[,1:5].